# Does changing pages titles in a website result in better SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords, meta-tags, title, meta-keywords

I am wondering whether I should have all pages in a website I am building with the same title or I should change the title for each of the pages, for an improved SEO strategy.

For example, I would think of having a generic title for the main page (with some keywords) and then more specific titles for the underlying pages depending on the content. But that way I would be covering more keywords and keyphrases.

Comment: **Every page** Should have an unique title, description and if you're feeling enthousiastic keywords. And unique content, but that should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Oh heck yeah! Create a specific titles per page.

Search engines use titles for a few things:

- To know the topic of the page.
- To gauge important topic keywords for the page.
- To create a search engine result page (SERP) link.

How SEO works in it's simplest form is that each page would have a `title` tag that uniquely describes the topic of that page. The `title` tag should contain the 2-3 most important keywords for the page topic and should not exceed approximately 50 characters. There should be one `h1` tag that supports the `title` tag but is not a duplicate of the `title` tag. It should compliment the `title` tag and should contain a 1-3 additional important keywords for your page topic. Any internal links (ones you made on your site) to your page should have link text that supports both the `title` tag and `h1` tag keywords.

`Title` tags, `h1` tags, and internal links should be conversational such as *How to assemble a widget.* and compelling to the user such as *Assembling a widget made easy.*

Your content should use all of your important keywords within the content and most importantly, in any subsequent header tags (`h2`, `h3`, ...).

As well, make sure your `description` meta-tag is compelling. This is often used for the SERP content snippet. When your description is served in the SERPs, you want it to be about 2-3 lines preferably and you want it to be conversational and compelling to the user.

This needs to planned out a bit. You can shoot from the hip on this, but do some keyword research anyway. It is likely, even for professionals, that content and tag tuning will be in order to improve performance. This comes after gauging performance and click through rates (CTR) over time. Each site is unique on this so there really is no formula.

Doing just these simple things well, is enough to perform well. You do want to begin a backlink campaign at some point when you have enough content created. However, creating good content and allowing others to link to you (known as organic links) is always the best option. But create backlinks anyway. Manually creating backlinks is still important. Avoid (for the most part) forums and blogs. You can use these things, but too much of this is a red-flag to search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is how it works. Duplicate page titles will have less effect. Also, various tools claim that you may encounter limits if if a page title is the same as the `<h1>` title. Its good to diversify those if you can.

In page title, there are about 60 chars that SERPS will display so prioritize the best or most useful keywords first. Google may still use words beyond 60, but its hit or miss and probably wont display them in SERP widget. For the `<h1>` title, you can use as many chars as you like, prioritize how you like.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Yes. Title play immensely an important role in SEO. Having your important keywords optimized in Titles gives better ranking. It is also important to limit your title word count under 60 characters. Using heading is beneficial.